# SQL Keep getting error with ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello everybody so i am working this "ON UPDATE CASCADE" feature and i still can't get it work.

my 1st table:

```
CREATE TABLE Stab
(
Stab_id int not null,
Sprache VARCHAR2(2000),
Vorname VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
Nachname VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
Geburtsatg date,
Nationalität VARCHAR2(2000),
Geschlecht VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
Kontakt VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (stab_id)
);
```

there is no problem with the 1st table

and i want my 2nd table with the first column "Stab_id" (like in the 1st table) is the foreign key of the 1st table. So when i change values in column "Stab_id" from 1st table, the "Stab_id" from 2nd table will change too.

```
CREATE TABLE Schauspieler
(
    Stab_id INT not null,
    Filmanzahl number(5,5),

    CONSTRAINT fk_Stabschau
    FOREIGN KEY (stab_id)
    REFERENCES stab (stab_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

But i keep getting error under the line "ON UPDATE CASCADE"

> Fehlerbericht - SQL-Fehler: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>
> *Cause:
>   *Action:

can someone please help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server doesn't like the data type `number(5,5)` or `VARCHAR2(2000)`.  Make those `decimal` and `varchar` respectively, and it runs just fine.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer. the data types are fine. i just......can't make the ON UPDATE CASCADE works

Comment: Update the tag on your question to be Oracle then.  I'm just saying you didn't specify your RDBMS, and the one I picked to check it out was wrong.  Save others the same pain by improving the tags on your question.

Comment: Oracle simply does not support `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause. The thing is, you know, you should never update primary keys. If you have a need to, then it is not in fact primary key and you probably need a "surrogate" key instead. And there is a great [post on AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034) on this subject too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle does not have "ON UPDATE CASCADE". You can manually emulate this behavior by using triggers

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is not supporting this functionality 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034

You have to write a Update Trigger on first table key column that does same operation in second table.

Danke